# How do I display value in a html field in a new window with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm basically trying to validate an input field, open a new window and display the contents of the input field in the new window. I got as far as opening the new window but will not post the text to field "displayText".

html:

```
<head>
    <title>Q3</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Form -->
  <form name="f3">
    Text: <input type="text" id="tb5" name="tb5"><br/>
    <button onclick="validateQ3()" Type="button" id="b1" name="b1">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

javascript:

```
function validateQ3() {
    // Get value from text box
    var a = document.getElementById("tb5").value;
        // Check that textbox is neither empty nor contains null
    if (a == null || a == "")
    {
        // if error, display error
        alert("Textbox cannot be empty");
        return false;
    }
    // Check text field >= 5
    if (a.length < 5)
    {
        alert("Field must be longer than 5 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Call newWindow() function
        newWindow(a);
    }
}//validateQ3()

function newWindow(a) {
    // Open new window
    var newWindow = window.open("", "mypopup", "height=300 , width=300");
    newWindow.document.write("<p id='displayText'></p>");
    if (window.focus)
    {
        newWindow.focus();
    }
    var tmp = newWindow.document;
    tmp.write('<html><head><title>mypopup</title></head>');
    tmp.write('<body><p id="displayText"></p></body></html>');
    document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = a;
    tmp.close();
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: The issue is probably calling `document.getElementById` instead of `tmp.getElementById`. `document` refers to `window.document` which is the current window, not the new window you opened

Comment: maybe you can find out where the error are: [Good luck](http://output.jsbin.com/loyopakiki)

Comment: Thanks Greg for taking the time to answer. That was the issue alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the innerHTML of the element on the current window and not the new window, displayText does not exist on the first window, change document to:

```
 tmp.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: Also, instead of `innerHTML` use `textContent` if you do not need `a` to undergo HTML parsing.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. Knew it had something to do with the windows but couldn't find the answer